# Silverlight - open to specific XAML page and the object tag

Tags: .net, silverlight, controls

I have a Silverlight app with two XAML Pages - MainPage and OtherPage
How can I add a reference to a page to open the Silverlight control to the specific page?

I have this

```
    <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Test.xap"/>
      <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
      <param name="background" value="white" />
      <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="3.0.40818.0" />
      <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
      <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=3.0.40818.0" style="text-decoration:none">
          <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
      </a>
    </object>
```

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
      <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Test.xap#OtherPage"/>
```

How is this done in Silverlight?
I'm just guessing here based off the old .NET control embed method
http://www.devhood.com/tutorials/tutorial_details.aspx?tutorial_id=187

Comment: Should I use InitParams? http://www.itscodingtime.com/post/Start-using-the-Silverlight-3cobject3e-tage280a6-Now!.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [RootVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.rootvisual(v=VS.95).aspx) property in the Application object:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    ...

    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RootVisual = new OtherPage();
    }
}
```